# How to count the nodes in a binary tree without using any extra memory

Tags: binary-tree, space-complexity

I recently had an interview for a position dealing with extremely large distributed systems, and one of the questions I was asked was to make a function that could count the nodes in a binary tree entirely in place; meaning no recursion, and no queue or stack for an iterative approach.

I don't think I have ever seen a solution that does not use at least one of the above, either when I was in school or after.

I mentioned that having a "parent" pointer would trivialize the problem somewhat but adding even a single simple field to each node in a tree with a million nodes is not trivial in terms of memory cost.

How can this be done?

Comment: use import ETE ...

Answer (score 1):

If an exact solution is required, then the prerequisite of being a binary tree may be a red herring. Each node in the cluster may simply count allocations in the backing collection. Which may be either constant or linear time, depending on whether it has been tracked or not.

If no exact solution was asked for, but the given tree is balanced, then a simple deep probe to determine tree hight, in combination with the placement rules allows to estimate an upper and lower bound for the total node count. Be wary that the probe may have either hit a node with height `log2(n)` or `log2(n) - 1`, so your estimate can be up to factor 2 too low or too high. Constant space, `O(log(n))` time.

If the placement rules dictate special properties about the bottom most layer (e.g. filled from left to right, not e.g. a red-black-tree), then you may perform `log(n)` probes in a binary search pattern to find the exact count, in constant space and `O(log(n)^2)` time.